# Exception occurred while calling driver.quit(): Unable to load configuration from class 'class GebConfig' (with environment: )

Tags: groovy, selenium-chromedriver, geb

I am running Groovy automation script, but i am getting the following error,

> Exception occurred while calling `driver.quit()`: Unable to load configuration from class 'class GebConfig' (with environment: )

Comment: Welcome to SO. With all due respect: Can you be any lazier? Where is your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: You will have to provide more information than this if you want anyone to be able to help you.